# Are there border checks on the Kosovo-Serbia (Mitrovica-Kraljevo) train?

Tags: trains, borders, serbia, kosovo

Next week I'm flying to Kosovo for three days, then continuing by Train from Mitrovica to Kraljevo in Serbia.

According to the timetable, the Train only stops at the Kosovo border Station (Jarinje) for two minutes, and at the Serbian border Station (Rudnica) for one Minute, with 10 minutes travel time between the two.

So are there actually any border checks on the Train?

I hold an EU ID Card btw, so doing this route is **not** a problem (unlike if I had been using a passport)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, Kosovar guards boarded at Jarinje (last Kosovo station) and briefly checked everyone for two minutes and then got off. Then at Rudnica (first Serbian station) Serbian guards boarded and started the check *after* the Train left the Station. They wrote down some stuff on a Piece of paper whilst checking everyone's ID (including my Swedish ID Card), and then got off the train at the next stop.

Exiting Serbia to Montenegro by bus was completely painless - they just took my ID for scanning and gave it back 10 minutes later

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it might be the answer that you need.

A few months ago, I tried to cross, by public bus, from Kosovo to Serbia. Serbia does not recognise Kosovo's independence so, technically, there is no border.

The formalities took only minutes, but there *was* a check on both sides of the 'border'. What's more, because I am neither Kosovar nor Serb (but hold a Dutch passport), I was not allowed to cross (by the Serbs) and had to make my way to Macedonia to get into Serbia.

Comment: Of course, because you used your passport, not your ID Card.

See, you can only enter Serbia from Kosovo with a passport *if* you entered Kosovo from Serbia (i.e. Serbia-Kosovo-Serbia). To be exact, you need to have a Serbian entry stamp.

ID Cards can't be stamped, however, so you would've been able to enter using it

Comment: Interesting point. Though, when I eventually did enter (and subsequently left) Serbia, I was not given a stamp either.